# Android Studio Get Advertisement Id with the official snippet

Tags: java, android, android-studio, code-snippets

```
has anyone managed to get the android advertisement Id in an app using the official snippet 

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/ad-id

I couldn't make this snippet to work in my app.

I have added the:
'''
dependencies {
  implementation 'androidx.ads:ads-identifier:1.0.0-alpha01'

  // Used for the calls to addCallback() in the snippets on this page.
  implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-android'
}
'''
And Gradle synced without any problems.

The code that's problematic is:
```

'''java

```
     ListenableFuture<AdvertisingIdInfo> advertisingIdInfoListenableFuture = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(getApplicationContext());
            Futures.addCallback(advertisingIdInfoListenableFuture,
                    new FutureCallback<AdvertisingIdInfo>() {                        
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(@NullableDecl AdvertisingIdInfo result) {
                            String myAdvertisementId = result.getId();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

                        }
            });
```

'''
    The error is:  error: method addCallback in class Futures cannot be applied to given types;
      required: ListenableFuture,FutureCallback,Executor

```
Supposedly it asks for executor but the official snippet is without one
```

Comment: Please share the code here what you have tried so far.

Comment: I've added the code. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you check the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/ad-id#kotlin), the kotlin snippet passes an `Executor` as the third parameter (the java sample misses one). So you should do the same in java:

```java
Futures.addCallback(advertisingIdInfoListenableFuture,
                    new FutureCallback<AdvertisingIdInfo>() {                        
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(@NullableDecl AdvertisingIdInfo result) {
                            String myAdvertisementId = result.getId();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

                        }
            }, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
```